# What is the best way to anchor a swing set for high usage by rambunctious children?

Tags: play-structures

At an organization where people take their children, I recently noticed that the swing-set was in poor condition, and being used hard by the children there.  The entire apparatus would shake and sway and also was leaning in a direction as though it would fall over.   I alerted the authorities of said organization, and they have removed the swings and locked the necessary doors to prevent access to it.

The organization wishes to repair or rebuild the swing set, but on the whole and given the rambunctiousness of the children I for one am uncertain how to proceed, though they await my suggestion and or action to correct the problem.

Metal and concrete sound the best, but there is still the issue of anchoring the swing set in place, and as I recall this is not a small matter as I had a swing set when I was a kid and due to lack of sufficient anchoring, my father took it down, never having found a solution to the anchoring issue.

Comment: Depending on the jurisdiction, there may be official rules regarding anchoring **and** also regarding the surface below the swing set. When I was a kid, concrete playgrounds were OK, but not any more - typically wood chips, rubber mats, etc. Often these things are grandfathered in, but once they close it up and then want to open up again, the current rules kick in.

Comment: It's been many years, but I'm pretty sure the swings at my elementary school were heavy steel galvanized pipe that was set deep in the ground - not the least bit portable nor particularly similar to a "home" set. Several "A-Frames" where the legs went unbroken/no joint into the ground, and a hefty pipe across those A-frames which the swings hung from. Probably was concrete down there below frost line, but we never saw it.

Comment: Agree with the comments. There's no corners to be cut here (public place), and you've just added some because it should be a total "rebuild" of a *'real'* swing set. Which probably means these days, also not high enough to be any fun.

Comment: There are companies that supply public playground structures that are designed to stand up to years of children's abuse

Comment: @ratchetfreak what are they called?

Comment: @leeand00 check "AAA state of play", a company like that can supply a swing set and surely advise on proper installation,

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to drive stakes into the ground at the legs, once the stakes are secure enough, screw the leg of the swing set securely to the stake.